# Full text search with mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I am trying to search an object using text as a parameter.

I have the following data in my mongodb:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59d518859eacefa4555d6edb",
        "id": "A07",
        "nome": "Outras doenças intestinais por protozoários"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59d518859eacefa4555d6edc",
        "id": "A08",
        "nome": "Infecções intestinais virais, outras e as não especificadas"
    }
]
```

My model:

```
var cid = new Schema({
    id: String,
    nome: String
}, {collection: 'cid'});

cid.index({'id': 'text', 'nome': 'text'});
```

Method to search:

```
var cid = require('./cid.model');

cid.find({$text: {$search: 'A07'}})
     .exec(function(err, result) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
       } else {
         res.json(result)
       }
     })
```

When I use 'A07' as parameter works.

But when I use 'Outras doenças intestinais por protozoários' as a parameter or some words, such as: 'doenças', 'outras' does not return anything.

What am I letting go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
cid.find({
        $or: [
            {name: new RegExp(your_variable, "i")},
            {id: new RegExp(your_variable, "i")}
        ]
    });
```